# trying to add a cover image to a product using api in prestashop 1.7.3.0

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have prestashop 1.7.3.0 installed and I'm trying to add a cover image to a product.

this is the class that I created with an addProductImage function

```
<?php

require_once _PS_ADMIN_CONTROLLER_DIR_ . 'AdminImportController.php';

class TuxInImage extends AdminImportControllerCore
{

    /**
     * @param $productId
     * @param $imgUrl
     * @param bool $regenerate
     * @throws PrestaShopDatabaseException
     * @throws PrestaShopException
     */
    public static function addProductImage($productId, $imgUrl, $isCover=false,$regenerate = true)
    {
        $img = new Image();
        $img->id_product = $productId;
        $img->cover=$isCover;
        $img->add();
        $imageId = $img->id;

        self::copyImg($productId, $imageId, $imgUrl, 'products', $regenerate);
    }
}
```

when I execute it, it adds the cover image. when I browse products on the admin panel.. I can properly see the image.

I noticed that when I open the website in my browser, it fails to load the images and it seems that they're missing some sort of a filename. it's looking for `.jpg` without first names.

for example: `http://MY_SITE_URL/2510-home_default/.jpg`

what am I missing ?

## update

the code in the template that shows the product image:

```
 <img
            src = "{$product.cover.bySize.home_default.url}"
            alt = "{if !empty($product.cover.legend)}{$product.cover.legend}{else}{$product.name|truncate:30:'...'}{/if}"
            data-full-size-image-url = "{$product.cover.large.url}"
          >
```

and this is the product class that uses the image class to create the cover image for the product:

```
require_once __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'TuxInImage.php';

class TuxInProduct {

    private $heLangId;
    private $enLangId;

    function __construct($heLangId,$enLangId)
    {
        $this->heLangId=$heLangId;
        $this->enLangId=$enLangId;
    }

    function addProduct($categoryId, $carListNTypeId, $productHebrewName, $productEnglishName, $manufacturerNameHe, $manufacturerNameEn, $price,$imgPath) {
        $productObj = new Product();
        $productObj->id_category_default=$categoryId;
        $productObj->price=$price;
        $productObj->name=[$this->heLangId=>$productHebrewName,$this->enLangId=>$productEnglishName];
        $productObj->manufacturer_name=[$this->heLangId=>$manufacturerNameHe,$this->enLangId=>$manufacturerNameEn];
        $productObj->quantity=0;
        $productObj->add();

        $productObj->setWsCategories([$categoryId]);
        $productId = $productObj->id;
        TuxInImage::addProductImage($productId,__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'tests'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'wind.jpg',true);
        ...
    }

}
```

## update 2

output of `var_dump` for `$product.cover`:

```
array (size=9)
  'bySize' => 
    array (size=5)
      'small_default' => 
        array (size=3)
          'url' => string 'http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-small_default/.jpg' (length=50)
          'width' => int 98
          'height' => int 98
      'cart_default' => 
        array (size=3)
          'url' => string 'http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-cart_default/.jpg' (length=49)
          'width' => int 125
          'height' => int 125
      'home_default' => 
        array (size=3)
          'url' => string 'http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-home_default/.jpg' (length=49)
          'width' => int 250
          'height' => int 250
      'medium_default' => 
        array (size=3)
          'url' => string 'http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-medium_default/.jpg' (length=51)
          'width' => int 452
          'height' => int 452
      'large_default' => 
        array (size=3)
          'url' => string 'http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-large_default/.jpg' (length=50)
          'width' => int 800
          'height' => int 800
  'small' => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string 'http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-small_default/.jpg' (length=50)
      'width' => int 98
      'height' => int 98
  'medium' => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string 'http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-home_default/.jpg' (length=49)
      'width' => int 250
      'height' => int 250
  'large' => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string 'http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-large_default/.jpg' (length=50)
      'width' => int 800
      'height' => int 800
  'legend' => string '' (length=0)
  'cover' => string '1' (length=1)
  'id_image' => string '7410' (length=4)
  'position' => string '1' (length=1)
  'associatedVariants' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

it seems that the false url of the image is missing the image id.

if I change `http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-small_default/.jpg` to `http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-small_default/1.jpg` that I see the first image in the db.

## ok.. in this update I figured out mostly what's going on..

the url http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-small_default/1.jpg is false. because it doesn't matter what number I add before the `.jpg`. it ignores it. it just needs at least one character.

in the following rewrite rules:

```
# Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
```

I needed to change all `.+\.jpg$` to `.*\.jpg$` for the rewrite to work on my images.

in the url `http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-home_default/.jpg`, 7410 is the image id, so I have no idea what data should be ignored before the `.jpg`.

now.. I'm guessing that I miss something and that is why I needed to change the
rewrite rules in .htaccess. any ideas what ?

Comment: File name is this 2510-home_default.jpg but you are looking for 2510-home_default/.jpg which means you have slash where you should not have it. Post line where you are displaying your image on frontend.

Comment: @Wr1t3r - thanks. updated main post

Comment: Try to var_dump($product.cover) to see whats in there.

Comment: @Wr1t3r - updated main post with the var_dump output. seems that the urls are broken there for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-home_default.jpg ? Just remove that slash? I'm pretty sure this is usuall format of prestashop images 7410-home_default.jpg

Comment: It's possible that function which is generating this array $product.cover is giving you wrong URL. Check that function and place where URL is generated.

Comment: @Wr1t3r - prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-home_default.jpg is false. prestashop is waiting to some sort of a tag... http://prestashop.ufk:8080/7410-small_default/this-is-my-tag.jpg will work. wondering what parameter I'm missing to add that info

Comment: It's probably image legend. Try to fill legend for that image to see if it's filled with it.

Comment: @Wr1t3r - I tried to add image->legend and product->meta_title but the problem still persists. i'll check the code that generates the url to find out what's missing

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what you need to do :)

Comment: @Wr1t3r - having problems finding out what code generates the $product object. got any ideas where to look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array you are working with is generated here:

```
/Adapter/Image/ImageRetriever.php -> public function getImage($object, $id_image)
```

Function which is generating your URL is here:

```
/classes/Link.php -> public function getImageLink($name, $ids, $type = null)
```

I think you will find out now what's wrong :)

Comment: yes.. my product was missing link_rewrite. thank you so much